# Toolbar back arrow is black in 4.0.3 version

Tags: android, back

Toolbar back arrow is white at higher android version 4.0.3 but Toolbar back arrow is black at android version 4.0.3. I would like to show white back arrow in all android version.

in java

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar.ActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar</item>

</style>
```

styles.xml (v21)

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

activity.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no style like `"@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"` on older devices (pre-5.0). also main parent should be `"@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` (or maybe without `ActionBar` at all? se last paragraph)

besides, for `Toolbar`:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"


<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

also: you can use `Toolbar` in all OS versions, you don't need to create separated style without `ActionBar` (assuming you are setting `Toolbar` programmatically) for newer OS versions

Comment: in styles.xml, can't solve **android:colorControlNormal** requires API level 21, current min is 15.

Comment: so you have also `colorControlNormal` without prefix, for earlier versions

Comment: How to do this. :D Please explain me, Thank You very much.

Comment: just keep both lines in this style, should compile without problem